Android TV remote control text input iOS
I'm developing an Android TV remote control app for iOS. So far, everything is working great—I'm able to discover devices, pair successfully, send navigation commands, and control media playback.
Is there a specific format or protocol requirement for sending text input to Android TV? For example, do I need to include additional metadata in the message?
How should I debug this issue? Is there a way to verify whether the text input is being received by the Android TV?
Has anyone else faced a similar issue while sending text inputs using this library? Any workarounds or tips would be greatly appreciated!
If needed, I can share snippets of my implementation for clarity. Thanks in advance!
I'm stuck on sending text input to the Android TV. Here's what I've done so far:
I'm using the AndroidTVRemoteControl library to manage the connection and commands.
I'm sending serialized text data using the RemoteImeBatchEdit message (from my proto generated file).
The serialized data is constructed with editInfo containing the text and encoded with length as varint before sending it to the remote device.
Despite this, the text does not appear on the Android TV's text fields. The connection and other commands are working fine, so I know the pairing and communication setup is correct.

did you solve the issue?

yes you need proto file to implement text input

can you share some piece of code?. i am confusing in imeObject, editInfo, imeBatchEdit

email me. I'll send you the project and explain

send me your mail in comment. my mail is muhammadasad5683@gmail.com

I have solved this problem after a lot of research.
you need proto file to implement text input
esp these parameters: imeObject, editInfo, imeBatchEdit

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
